# UNION in MySQL using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, union

I have problem when using UNION problem: I have 2 tables `TOPIK` and `SUBTOPIK` which I do left join and right join then make union of them using the following statement:

```
mySqlStmt = "SELECT *
FROM TOPIK
LEFT OUTER JOIN SUBTOPIK
ON TOPIK.IDTOPIK=SUBTOPIK.IDTOPIK
WHERE (TOPIK.TARGETNPMHS LIKE '%0000312100006%'
OR ((TOPIK.TARGETOBJECTNICKNAME LIKE '%OPERATOR KEPALA BAA%'
OR TOPIK.TARGETOBJECTNICKNAME LIKE '%OPERATOR BAA%' )
AND TOPIK.TARGETNPMHS IS NULL))
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TOPIK
RIGHT OUTER JOIN SUBTOPIK
ON TOPIK.IDTOPIK=SUBTOPIK.IDTOPIK
WHERE (SUBTOPIK.NPMHSRECEIVER LIKE '%0000312100006%'
OR ((SUBTOPIK.OBJNICKNAMERECEIVER LIKE '%OPERATOR KEPALA BAA%'
OR SUBTOPIK.OBJNICKNAMERECEIVER LIKE '%OPERATOR BAA%' )
AND SUBTOPIK.NPMHSRECEIVER IS NULL))"
```

The code above works on mysql workbench, but when i use it in java,

```
get connection...bla..bla;
stmt =  con.prepareStatement("mySqlStmt");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
  String topik_idTopik = ""+rs.getLong("TOPIK.IDTOPIK");
}
```

i got

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'TOPIK.IDTOPIK' not found.
```

but both `TOPIK` and `SUBTOPIK` have this column.

Comment: just use `IDTOPIK` instead of `TOPIK.IDTOPIK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column's alias is `IDTOPIK`, you should not use the fully qualified name:

```
stmt =  con.prepareStatement(mySqlStmt);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
  String topik_idTopik = ""+rs.getLong("IDTOPIK");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I believe mysql will ask for which table since IDTOPIK cols can be found on both table.

Comment: @fajarsetiawan No it doesn't. In JDBC (and also the SQL standard), columns are requested by label only. The original table name or table-alias is irrelevant. If there are multiple columns with the same label in a `ResultSet`, the first column with that label is returned.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel ur right sir, thanks. just did what ur recommended. fix. thx

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause undoes the right outer join.  You might as well do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TOPIK t  LEFTJOIN
     SUBTOPIK s
     ON t.IDTOPIK = s.IDTOPIK
WHERE (s.NPMHSRECEIVER LIKE '%0000312100006%' OR
       (s.OBJNICKNAMERECEIVER LIKE '%OPERATOR KEPALA BAA%' OR 
        s.OBJNICKNAMERECEIVER LIKE '%OPERATOR BAA%'
        ) AND 
        s.NPMHSRECEIVER IS NULL
       )
      );
```

Of course, the problem you have is with the alias, not the join, but you might as well have a correct query.